# Android:Unable to read from xml

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

While trying to read from xml , I am getting `IOException`.

Following is the code

```
File xmlFile = new File("\\assets\\data\\data.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
```

`dBuilder.parse(xmlFile)` is throwing an `IOException`.

I have tried `new File("/assets/data/data.xml")` and `new File("assets/data/data.xml")` also but with no use. What could be the possible error and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 1):

You do not access `assets/` at runtime using `File`. You should access `assets/` at runtime using `AssetManager`, which you can get via `getResources().getAssets()`.

For more info see [Android parse XML file from Assets or internal/external storage](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/10/android-parse-xml-file-from-assets-or.html)

Get xml from Assets as

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(getXml(context,"data/data.xml")));
Document doc =  builder.parse(is);
```

And function is

```
private String getXml(Context mContext,String path){

    String xmlString = null;
    AssetManager am = mContext.getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream is = am.open(path);
        int length = is.available();
        byte[] data = new byte[length];
        is.read(data);
        xmlString = new String(data);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    return xmlString;
}
```

Comment: just asking something off topic to this question . .data.xml contains the data for the app so is assets ideal folder to keep this xml file in ?

Comment: @LearningBasics-Android It depends,what type of data(private or public) you want to save

Comment: @LearningBasics-Android see updated answer to get xml file from assets.

Answer (score 0):

Please try Something like this

```
AssetManager assetManager = getBaseContext().getAssets();

 try{
   InputStream is = assetManager.open("data.xml");
   SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
   SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
   XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

   OrderXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new OrderXMLHandler();
   xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
   InputSource inStream = new InputSource(is);
   xr.parse(inStream);

   String dataField1 = myXMLHandler.getDataField1(); //Use your fields in the data.xml file
   String dataField2 = myXMLHandler.getDataField2(); //Use your fields in the data.xml file
 is.close();

 } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy your file to the Internal Cache of your Application like this

```
  InputStream xmlIS = getAssets.open("data/data.xml");

  File xmlFile = new File(getCacheDir(), "data.xml");
  FileOutputStream xmlStream = new FileOutputStream(xmlFile);

  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int read = -1;
  while((read = xmlIs.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        xmlStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
        xmlStream.flush();
  }
```

Now you can set xmlFile as input of `dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);`

If you want to save it permanently change, `getCacheDir()` to `getFilesDirectory()` and do something like this

```
  File xmlFile = new File(getFilesDirectory(), "data.xml");
  if(!xmlFile.exists()) {
  ... // the code which is above
  }
```

then pass `xmlFile` to `dbBuilder.parse` function.

hope it will help.

regards
Moonzai